# what should be the program or script for task scheduler

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

Through `cmd`, this command works fine and my service `ABC` gets terminate and starts,

```
 taskkill /f /fi "memusage gt 100" /im ABC.exe && NET START ABC
```

Now I want to create a task scheduler to run this script every day,

- In `Add Arguments`, I put the command.
- if I am putting `CMD` in `program\script`, then it's not working, what shall I put there?

or do we have other way to get it done?

[image]

Comment: I take it you solved your [previously closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63810009), but instead of providing feedback, you simply deleted it. Your question is about Windows Task Scheduler and how to use it, this is essentially a software question, and should be asked and answered on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), not on StackOverflow.

Comment: This isn't even a `batch-file` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `/C` to the `cmd.exe` arguments followed by the command you want to execute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Program/script:

```
cmd.exe
```

Arguments:

```
/S /C "taskkill /f /fi "memusage gt 100" /im ABC.exe && NET START PeerDistSvc"
```

Where flags from `cmd /?`:

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then
> terminates
>
> /S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K
>
> ...
>
> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic
> is used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If ...:
>
>    - no /S switch
>      ...
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>    a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>    remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>    any text after the last quote character.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively put your command into a script file say "mycommand.cmd"

MyCommand.cmd:

```
taskkill /f /fi "memusage gt 100" /im ABC.exe && NET START ABC
```

then just reference this CMD /BAT file in the action of the task scheduler.

This is the easiest option when you have anything complex or will want to modify the code in any way on a regular basis because modifying the code in the scheduled task itself will always require entering your credentials to edit it.

In addition if you have a separate script file you can manually run it by hand as needed without opening the scheduler and running the task on demand.